# Convert form to xml

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, xml

Is there a way to turn a form or the information in the form to XML without code. Once a user submits the form i want to take the information (fields) into XML to then email it off. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Save the form locally and then change the extensions of the file to `.cab`. Then you should open this file and it will contain the XML files for the form. Then you can send the XML file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to automate this process with a workflow. How will i go about doing that?

Comment: Workflows don't have methods to do this. So either you would have to add custom actions that do this or add solutions to the site that would handle this. Look into event handlers they may help you.

Comment: problem is that I cant use code on these forms, would be 1000 times easier if i could. I'll look into custom actions and solutions. Any direction on what i should be looking for here?

Comment: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-build-and-deploy-workflow-custom-actions This should help.